# AWS outbound api call with dynamic(custom) text and phone call with text-to-speech?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

**Requirement:** Have to make a phone call to the user and there will be voice message to be played.

---

**Step#1:**

Make startoutboundvoicecontact API call in php. Below are links for AWS API call and it's related attributes.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/APIReference/API_StartOutboundVoiceContact.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-connect-2017-08-08.html#startoutboundvoicecontact

**Step#2:**

AWS will run specific Contact flow with the "predefined voice message in Play Prompt"(Need to make this dynamic which will come from api) and make a call to the user.

**Step#3:**

A user will pick up the call and listen to the voice message and call will be auto disconnected or a user can disconnect by choice.

---

**Question#1:** Is it possible to pass "Dynamic Text" in startoutboundvoicecontact API?

**Question#2:** In Step#1, Contact flow -> Play Prompt has Text-To-Speech -> Enter Dynamically option, but I am not quite sure how it works?

**Question#3:** Any other api will be helpful to achieve above functionality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes this is all doable with the API, I just implemented the same flow in javascript, but the main parts should be the same.

1. Create a contact flow in the AWS connect app with the following setup:

[image: contact flow]

2. The key is to add the dynamic attribute in the play prompt with the `$.Attributes` variable. Click the `Play prompt` in the contact flow and add the text you want to be spoken in the call. I used SSML, this might also work for text:

[image]

Remember to **Save and Publish** the contact flow.

3. Now with the sdk add the message parameter to your attributes:

Javascript:

```
const connect = new aws.Connect();
var params = {
    Attributes: {'message' : 'my dynamic message'},
    ContactFlowId: 'your contact flow guid (found from url in browser)', /* required */
    DestinationPhoneNumber: 'phonenumber to call', /* required */
    InstanceId: 'your connect instance id (found from url in browser)', /* required */
    SourcePhoneNumber: 'phone number you claimed in connect'
};
connect.startOutboundVoiceContact(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) { console.log('Error', err.stack) }
    else { console.log('Success') }
});
```

PHP might look something like this (sorry, never coded PHP..):

```
$result = $client->startOutboundVoiceContact([
    'Attributes' => array('message' => 'my dynamic message'),
    'ContactFlowId' => 'your contact flow guid (found from url in browser)' // REQUIRED
    'DestinationPhoneNumber' => 'phonenumber to call', // REQUIRED
    'InstanceId' => 'your connect instance id (found from url in browser)', // REQUIRED
    'SourcePhoneNumber' => 'phone number you claimed in connect',
]);
```

Comment: Where to put this javascript. I'm a beginner.

Comment: This completely depends on what you are trying to do, I'm running a Node.js server which I use to call the connect apis with the SDK to make the calls

Comment: I can make call to US number but unable to make call to Indian number. Is there any way to make call to India ? code: 'DestinationNotAllowedException', time: 2018-09-15T13:47:47.150Z, requestId: 'edb4f77f-b8ed-11e8-a695-97cd86ca4cfa', statusCode: 403, retryable: false, retryDelay: 41.39885160985075 }

Comment: This is likely something related to your account, you should try looking aws support / faq pages

Comment: I have requested amazon support to enable international call. They enabled, Now I can make outbound call to India.